# What are the health hazards of using laundry detergent to wash dishes?

Tags: toxicity, chemical

I've used laundry detergent many times to wash my dish prior to eating. Sometimes I washed the mug with it as well. I was not very cautious about the fact that it was meant to clean only laundry and a very strong chemical. At the moment I'm a bit scared. Can anybody tell me what should I do now?